# How To Capture the AR View on iOS in vuforia sdk

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using vuforia SDK for an augmented reality application. The problem is when try to capture the current camera frame its always give black image

Answer (score 0):

senario 1:

if u r set camera_default its always back camera.

if u want front camera : CAMERA_FRONT

senario 2:

if u r using AVCaptureDeviceInput class:

```
 AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *discoverySession = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:allTypes mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo position:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
```

u can set as per ur requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If I m understand you correctly, you have got the current `Frame` object in Vuforia, but translate it to UIImage object and the image was black. So I think the problem is the PIXEL_FORMAT you are not set right.

Here is what I get a UIImage object from `Frame` Object:

```
- (UIImage *)createUIImage:(const Vuforia::Image *)image
{
    int width = image->getWidth();
    int height = image->getHeight();
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = Vuforia::getBitsPerPixel(Vuforia::RGB888);
    int bytesPerRow = image->getBufferWidth() * bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaNone;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, image->getPixels(), Vuforia::getBufferSize(width, height, Vuforia::RGB888), NULL);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return result;
}
```

The `Vuforia::Image` object is from `const Vuforia::Image *image = frame.getImage(i);`

As you probably notice the pixel format I m setting is `Vuforia::RGB888` and you should not forget set the same format before you make a screenshot `Vuforia::setFrameFormat(Vuforia::RGB888, true);`

I m using this method to get a User Define Target(UDT) image and upload to Vuforia Cloud. If you have any other idea please do tell me, thanks!